# echo current taxonomy id for this loop?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I have this query to get posts and show like this:

```
Custom taxonomy 1
<div ID1>
 |-- post 1
 |-- post 2
</div>   
Custom taxonomy 2
<div ID2>
 |-- post 3
 |-- post 4
</div>
```

Now I need to get the current taxonomy ID for each section and insert to < div **ID**>. How to request & echo the ID in this code?

```
<?php

  $taxid = get_the_terms( $post->ID , get_cat_slug() );
    if($taxid) {
        foreach( $taxid as $xid ) {
            echo $xid->term_id;
        }
    }
  // for a given post type, return all
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    $tax = get_cat_slug();

    $tax_terms = get_terms(
        $tax, array(
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ));

    if ($tax_terms) {
        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'caller_get_posts' => 1,
                ); // END $args

            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($my_query->have_posts()) { ?>

                <div id="ID"> <!-- I need ID insert here -->

                <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                  <!-- I need ID insert in HTML here -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>

            <?php } // END if have_posts loop
            wp_reset_query();
        } // END foreach $tax_terms
    } // END if $tax_terms

    ?>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, the current term you are iterating is `$tax_term`:

```
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
```

so within that block, the term's ID is `$tax_term->term_id`:

```
<div id="<?php echo $tax_term->term_id; ?>">
```

Comment: How do I get taxonomy link? <?php echo get_category_link( $tax_term->term_id ) ?> return nothing

Comment: `echo get_term_link( $tax_term )` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array('post_type'   => $post_type,
                'numberposts'   => $numberOfPost,
                'order'         => 'DESC'
            );
$tax_query = array(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     =>$terms
$args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
```

Here's a sample meta query. Use this incase you need meta query as well.

```
$meta_query = array('relation'      => 'AND',
                    array(  'key'       => $key_here,
                            'value'     => $value
                    ),
                    array(  'key'       => $other_key,
                            'value'     => $vaue,
                            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                );
$args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
```

And Now pass $args in WP_Query

```
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Let me know incase it doesn't help.